# InDesign script labels in appscript python module

Tags: python, adobe-indesign, py-appscript

I'm using appscript to create an InDesign document from Database data, but I can't seem to figure out how to set the contents of the objects in my page. In older versions of ID (CS4 and earlier, if i'm correct) I could get the object with script label `foo` by calling `spread.page_items['foo']`. However, this does not seem to work anymore. `spread.page_items.ID(<foo_id>).label.get()` does show `foo`, so the script label is set correctly.

The Adobe documentation speaks of a label property, however I haven't yet figured out how to use that property to correctly select the right object.

If there is a way to obtain an object's ID easily, that might also do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this after finding [this article](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/py-appscript/doc_3x/appscript-manual/09_referenceforms.html) about references in appscript. I had to use a filter, like so: `spread.page_items[its.label == 'foo']`.

Also, as suggested by Youngware below, the script labels support is indeed replaced by layer names.

Comment: For a discussion on your `label` troubles, read the Adobe Forums discussion [With CS5, some things have changed](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/615381); its handling labels differently is discussed and options are given (for ExtendScript, but it seems this ought to work for your scripting language as well).

Comment: If the newer InDesign versions indeed support the use of layer names, that would be even better. Thanks for the link!